# samsung galaxy s5 screen blink problem

Tags: screen, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I am using Samsung Galaxy S5 `android 6.0.1`, after `marshmallow` update i am facing **screen blinking** problem. when i unlock screen it started blinking. and when i open hayday Game, it stopped blinking. so anyone tell me what should be the issue for this problem?

Comment: What is *hayday* application?

Comment: Hayday is a game.

Comment: Try wiping cache partition, it may be that old files there are causing the problem

Comment: @MANI if hayday is a game then why it shows in application's list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution:

Go to settings >> system >> About device.

Find "**Build number**" and click 6 times fast on it.

It will enable **developer options** menu in settings.

Come back to Home Screen, and then go back to Settings >> system >> Now you will see the **Developer Options** menu

Now go to Developer options >> Drawing Section or Rendering Section >> Find "**Turn off hardware overlays**" or "**disable hardware overlays**" >> This will force the phone to always use GPU for screen adjustments.

Restart your device and see no more screen blinking.